# Update parent class variable from child class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

The code below has two classes, and I am trying to update the parent class variable from the `Child1` class.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shared_variable = "I am a shared variable"

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def change_variable(self, new_value):
        self.shared_variable = new_value

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# Example usage:
child1_instance = Child1()
child2_instance = Child2()

print(child1_instance.shared_variable)  # Initial value

child1_instance.change_variable("New value from Child1")

print(child2_instance.shared_variable)  # Updated value accessed by Child2
```

However, after updating the value of the `shared_variable` using the `child1_instance`, the output shown by `child2_instance` is still the same. How can I rectify this?

The desired output is:

```
I am a shared variable
New value from Child1
```

Comment: Just having "shared" in the name of a variable does not make it shared!  This is an ordinary instance attribute, stored separately for each instance of `Parent` and its subclasses, as would anything that is stored via `self.whatever = ...`.  An actual shared attribute would be initialized in a class body, rather than in a method, and would have to be changed via `classname.whatever = ...`.

Comment: @jasonharper: Could you provide an example

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Off the top of my head, I can't think of any reason to modify a parent class from a child class. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F).). Would  you like to tell us why you want this behavior?

Comment: A variable that uses `self.` is certainly NOT shared.  Why did you think it was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite its name, the `shared_variable` you're creating in `Parent.__init__` is not in fact being shared between anything. It's initialized uniquely for each instance of any of your classes. You can see this if you create two `Parent` instances and modify them to have different values:

```
p1 = Parent()
p2 = Parent()

p1.shared_variable = "foo"
print(p2.shared_variable) # still prints "I am a shared variable" here
```

If you want all the instances to be referencing the same variable, you need to use a class variable, defined at the top level of the class, outside the methods:

```
class Parent:
    shared_variable_for_real = "I am a shared variable"
```

You can still look this variable up with `self.shared_variable_for_real`, but only to read it. If you want to rebind the shared variable you must use `Parent.shared_variable_for_real`. If you try writing to the attribute on `self`, you'll get an instance variable, like you do with your current code.

Note that the issue with subclasses is mostly a red herring in this problem. You can rebind the value of `Parent.shared_variable_for_real` from anywhere, *including* any of its subclasses. If you *just* want to rebind the value for one branch of the descendents of `Parent`, you could write to `Child1.shared_variable_for_real`, which would be seen by those instances, but not the instance of any sibling subclasses. That doesn't seem like what you want, so I suspect just using `Parent.shared_variable_for_real` everywhere is what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide a complete code

Comment: @PrateekDaniels this answer explains exactly what is wrong and how to fix it. Do you have clarifying questions?

Comment: @Prateek We don't have a complete solution because it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. See my comment on your question along with Hai Vu's. And note that Blckknght wrote "I **suspect** [this] is what you are after."

Comment: It's worth noting you can use `type(self).shared_variable_for_real` in a method to set the attribute on the class